# in swift. when i create two sound files with the name, does the second on replace the first one?

Tags: swift, nsurl, avaudiorecorder

Im trying to make a recorder in swift and i ran into this problem. if i create two sound file with the same name, does the first file get replaced by the second file or the first file still exist but i just cannot find it?

here is my code:

func setup_recorder**strong text**(){

```
    var recordSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
    ]

    time_display_1 = 0
    timer_1 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "timer_update_1", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    var dir_path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    var doc_dir: AnyObject = dir_path[0]
    var sound_file_path = doc_dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("1.m4a")
    sound_file_URL_1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: sound_file_path)
    let file_manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if file_manager.fileExistsAtPath(sound_file_path) {
        println("sound exists")
    }        

    var error: NSError?
    recorder_1 = AVAudioRecorder(URL: sound_file_URL_1!, settings: recordSettings, error: &error)
    if let e = error {
        println(e.localizedDescription)
    }
    else {
        recorder_1.meteringEnabled = true
        recorder_1.prepareToRecord()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if i create two sound file with the same name, does the first file get replaced by the second

**Yes**, `AVAudioRecorder` will overwrite, i.e. replace, an existing file with the new data. To avoid that, check whether the file exists first and pick a different name if it does.